# How to allow certain clients to talk to others in the same IP range when client-to-client communication is prevented?

Tags: iptables, firewall, vpn, openvpn

I have a tap0 VPN working. In order to make the customers not talk I commented the `#client-to-client` line, it worked.

Now I want to leave some IPs talking to the customers. Eg:10.8.0.2 and 10.8.0.6 can talk to everyone from range 10.8.0.0./24.

How should I do?

Comment: This SF Q/A should help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client

Answer (score 2):

In OpenVPN server's config file `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`, make sure that `client-to-client` line is disabled or removed so that `iptables` can manipulate such packets. Then assign static IP address to the two clients that should talk to rest of clients. Then use iptables to block communication between unauthorized clients.

Assign static IP addresses to users tom and jerry

```
$ sudo echo "tom,10.0.8.2" >> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
$ sudo echo "jerry,10.0.8.6" >> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
# Then restart openvpn service
$ systemctl restart openvpn@server
```

Then add iptables rules to FORWARD chain, keeping in mind that rules are processed top down (`10.0.8.1` belongs to OpenVPN server)

```
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.8.1 -d 10.0.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.8.2 -d 10.0.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.8.6 -d 10.0.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Assuming OpenVPN server uses tun0, block unauthorized client-to-client
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun0 -j DROP
```

If `client-to-client` is enabled, `iptables` cannot manipulate this kind of traffic because it is not pushed to the kernel

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client